# How do you format the legend in Geoserver when using GetLegendGraphic?

Tags: geoserver, legend, formatting

I'm new to the world of GIS and geoserver so sorry if I'm asking an obvious or simple question.

I'm using GetLegendGraphic to create a legend for a raster layer on the server, as it stands it looks like this:

[image: legend]

http://norsewind.eu:8080/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=20&HEIGHT=20&SCALE=160000000&LAYER=norse:norse_map_1

I'd like to know how to format the numbers to a specific number of decimal points.  Also I don't need the '=x' part, can that be removed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The text parts are controlled in the SLD colormap label, ie

```
    <ColorMapEntry color="#FFFF00" quantity="0.25" label="0.25"/>
```

I don't think either of your questions can be handled from the GetLegendGraphic request.